# Match string between special characters

Tags: python, regex

I've messed around with regex a little bit but am pretty unfamiliar with it for the most part. The string will in the format:

```
\n\n*text here, can be any spaces, etc. etc.*
```

The string that I will get will have two line breaks, followed by an asterisk, followed by text, and then ending with another asterisk.

I want to exclude the beginning `\n\n` from the returned text.  This is the pattern that I've come up with so far and it seems to work:

```
pattern = "(?<=\\n\\n)\*(.*)(\*)"

match = re.search(pattern, string)
if match:
    text = match.group()
    print (text)
else:
    print ("Nothing")
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way to go about matching this pattern or if the way I'm handling it is okay.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid capturing groups and have the whole match as result using:

```
pattern = r'(?<=\n\n\*)[^*]*(?=\*)'
```

Example:

```
import re
print re.findall(r'(?<=\n\n\*)[^*]*(?=\*)','\n\n*text here, can be any spaces, etc. etc.*')
```

If you want to include the asterisk in the result you can use instead:

```
pattern = r'(?<=\n\n)\*[^*]*\*'
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand your regex.  It does a positive lookbehind for `\n\n*`.  The next part (`[^*]*`) I'm not familiar with. The last section then just does a lookahead (I think?) for the last asterik.

Comment: @joshft91: `[^*]` is a character class that contains all characters except `*`, then `[^*]*` is "all characters except `*` zero or more times." . The goal of the last lookhead is to exclude the last `*` from match result.

Comment: Thank you. What would happen if an asterisk showed up in the text?  I would assume that would mess it up since I have no other way to identify the end of the text.

Comment: @joshft91: you are right. It is the reason why you must clearly define the rules. Note that your pattern will fail is your string contains a newline before the `*`

Comment: If it contains a newline before which asterisk? Seems like it shouldn't, but I am most likely wrong.

Comment: @joshft91: Before the second

Comment: Okay, I just used the pattern that you had in your answer and I get something like this back: `["text here"]`. I'd like to keep the asterisks in the response and also not include the brackets and quotes. I know in the grouping that I had earlier, the brackets and quotes were not part of the string match.

I tried this: `pattern = r'(?<=\n\n)\*[^*]*(\*)'`, but only got ['*'] back.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39844/discussion-between-joshft91-and-casimir-et-hippolyte)

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are overkill in a case like this -- if the delimiters are always static and at the head/tail of the string:

```
>>> s = "\n\n*text here, can be any spaces, etc. etc.*"
>>> def CheckString(s):
...     if s.startswith("\n\n*") and s.endswith("*"):
...         return s[3:-1]
...     else:
...         return "(nothing)"
>>> CheckString(s)
'text here, can be any spaces, etc. etc.'
>>> CheckString("no delimiters")
'(nothing)'
```

(adjusting the slice indexes as needed -- it wasn't clear to me if you want to keep the leading/trailing '*' characters. If you want to keep them, change the slice to

```
return s[2:]
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting, I didn't think of doing it this way.  Thought it'd be a fun way to mess around with regex, but this way is a little more straight forward.  I'll have to give my answer to the other guy since it pertains to my post, but I'll probably just implement this instead.

Comment: Actually, I just wasn't thinking before.  There can be any amount of text before the `\n\n*` occurs, so I think regex would be the best way to go.

Comment: Unintended SO effect: you're supposed to reduce your problem to its simplest form, and as a result some of your answers solve the simple version, not the real one. :)